# How to deal with different type of users with rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

I need to know, if there is a way to deal with different type of users/clients in Rails using a single model.

What I really need to do?
 - I need to save a different type of clients in my database. So, I have this migration:

```
class CreateClients < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :clients do |t|
      t.string :name                       # Person name if "Personal", Company name if  type "Company"
      t.string :nif                        # fillable only if type is Company
      t.string :identity_card_number       # fillable only if type is Personal
      t.integer :client_type               # Type can be Personal or Company
      t.references :company, index: true   # if type is personal, it can belong to a company
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Then I create this model

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :employees, class_name: 'Client', foreign_key: 'company_id'
    belongs_to :company, class_name: 'Client'
end
```

Note: A personal account can belong to a company or not.

Based on your experience, am I doing this in the right way? There are another way to do that?

**EDIT:**

Hi @manfergo25,

Whit this I have another question. "Company" and "Personal" are both "Clients Account", in that way, both must be able to buy services.

If I need to associent the client with the service, can I do this?

```
class Personal < Account
   has_many :services
end
```

and

```
class Service < ...
   belongs_to :account
end
```

??

Comment: You can use `STI(Single Table Inheritance)`, like `class User < ActiveRecord::Base`, then user can be a `class PersonalUser < User` or `class CompanyUser < User`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way is Single Table Inheritance (STI) as Sontya say.

```
  class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  end
```

Then,

```
  class Client < Account
  end

  class Provider < Account
  end
```

You only have to add a type column in 'Account' to contain a string representing the type of the stored object.

For example in a controller you could do this:

```
account = Client.find(params[:autocomplete_client])     
params[:service][:account_id] = account.id
@service = Service.new(params[:service])
```

Comment: Hi @manfergo25,

Whit this I have another question. "Company" and "Personal" are both "Clients Account", in that way, both must be able to buy services.

If I need to associent the client with the service, can I do this?

class Personal < Account
   has_many :services
end

and

class Service < ...
   belongs_to :account
end

??

Comment: Yes, sure. You can do that!

Comment: only to be clear... at this case, both will share the same table "clients", right?

Comment: Yes, the same table 'accounts' in db. But you can call ´clients´in the business logic and it will return only the accounts object filtering by ´Client´. I write an example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use STI(Single Table Inheritance)

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Company < Account
    has_many :services, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Personal < Account
    has_many :services, :dependent => :destroy

end

class Service < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to: personal
    belongs_to: company
end
```

With the above definition, a `personal` and `company` should be able to buy services.
and you should be able to call
`@company.services` # it will return you the number of services of company 
`@personal.services` # it will return you the number of services of personal

Comment: in this case I will have only on table "Accounts" right?

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I think the way you have suggested in your question is the way I'd do it.

While Single Table Inheritance is intellectually better modelling -- I've found STI to be a bit hard to work with and sometimes unreliable in Rails.  And probably won't improve the cleanliness or conciseness of your code all that much in the end anyway. STI is good to keep in mind as an option, if you find the OP approach is not working well as far as allowing you to write clear concise code and it seems STI could work out better.

But I'd start without STI, with just the one Client class, as you've outlined in your question.  If you later add STI, you'd still have the Client class, you'd just have sub-classes for, say, PersonalClient and CompanyClient. It won't be that hard to switch to STI later if you want to, although it might require some minor db schema alterations.

But I don't think it'll get you enough benefit to justify the added complexity, in an area of Rails that has sometimes had some rough edges.

Here's some more info about STI and it's plusses and minuses: http://eewang.github.io/blog/2013/03/12/how-and-when-to-use-single-table-inheritance-in-rails/